# Looking for a VBA code to combine unsaved Excel workbooks into a consolidated workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which spits out multiple copies of a timesheet with varying pieces of data within it. Excel names these 'book1, book2' etc. I'm looking for a way to combine all these unsaved workbooks into a consolidated workbook without having to save them in a folder location first. I've been trying to tweak the below code but it doesn't do what i want. Let me know if you can help

```
Sub MergeSheets2()
    'Updated by Extendoffice 2019/2/20
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xStrFName As String
    Dim xWS As Worksheet
    Dim xMWS As Worksheet
    Dim xTWB As Workbook
    Dim xStrAWBName As String
    Dim xI As Integer
    
    On Error Resume Next 
    xStrPath = " C:\Users\DT168\Desktop\KTE\"
    xStrName = "Book1,Book2,Book3,Book4"
    xArr = Split(xStrName, ",")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set xTWB = ThisWorkbook
    xStrFName = Dir(xStrPath & "*.xlsx")
    
    Do While Len(xStrFName) > 0
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=xStrPath & xStrFName, ReadOnly:=True
        xStrAWBName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        For Each xWS In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            For xI = 0 To UBound(xArr)
                If xWS.Name = xArr(xI) Then
                    xWS.Copy After:=xTWB.Sheets(xTWB.Sheets.count)
                    Set xMWS = xTWB.Sheets(xTWB.Sheets.count)
                    xMWS.Name = xStrAWBName & "(" & xArr(xI) & ")"
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next xI
        Next xWS
        Workbooks(xStrAWBName).Close
        xStrFName = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this code just limited to ` "Book1,Book2,Book3,Book4" ` being the workbooks to consolidate?  If not, but the contents of a folder, I'd just look at replacing `xArr(xI)` with some naming convention based on `xWS.name`  also removing `For xI = 0 To UBound(xArr)`  and                 `If xWS.Name = xArr(xI) Then`  Why are you checking a folder if they are unsaved?

Comment: The code you have here, if I'm not mistaken, is checking a folder for all .xlsx files and then copying in all the sheets named `Book1`-`Book4` into the WB running the code. This seems to be something that only can be done after you described scenario. If you want to merge them before they are saved, you need to change the code that creates those workbooks in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Nathan & Christofer for your input. It seems apparent that this code isn't what i'm after. What i need is a code to combine all workbooks with names book1-book20 into one workbook. This combined workbook would be separate from the original workbook which ran the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should create a new workbook and then copy all the sheets from existing workbooks named Book1, Book2, etc. into the new workbook.  It makes no checks to see if the workbooks actually exist.  Adjust the size of the loop to account for however many books you have created.

It does not save the new book after the sheets are copied in, or delete the sheets that were present when wbAll was created, nor does it check to make sure there are no sheet name conflicts when the sheets are copied into wbAll.

You will want to implement all of these checks.  Further, it seems unlikely to me that your books will always be named Book1, Book2, Book3, Book4, etc.  The numbering for new books is sequential, and it keeps incrementing the entire time that Excel is open, so the first four books will be called 1, 2, 3, 4, but the next four will be 5, 6, 7, 8.  It would probably be better to keep track of the names of the created books (or references to the actual books), and then use those directly instead of trying to construct the name on the fly afterward.

```
Sub joinBooks()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbAll As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set wbAll = Workbooks.Add

    For t = 1 To 4
                    
        Set wb = Workbooks("Book" & t)

        For Each ws In wb.Sheets                
            ws.Copy after:=wbAll.Sheets(Sheets.Count)                
            Next
        
        Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. This worked really well. I only changed the WS.COPY for WS.MOVE so I didn't have multiple copies of the same sheet. I also had to insert an 'on error exit sub' but i'm sure this is down to my sheet. Thanks for the assist

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MergeSheets2()

    Const FOLDER = "C:\Users\DT168\Desktop\KTE\"
    
    Dim sFName As String, x as String, n As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbAll As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wbAll = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' 1 sheet
    n = 1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    sFName = Dir(FOLDER & "Book*.xlsx")
    Do While Len(sFName) > 0
        x = Mid(sFName, 5, Len(sFName) - 9)
        If IsNumeric(x) Then
            
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER & sFName, 1, 1)
            For Each ws In wb.Sheets
                ws.Copy after:=wbAll.Sheets(n)
                n = n + 1
                wbAll.Sheets(n).Name = "Book" & x & "_" & ws.Name
            Next
            wb.Close False

        End If
        sFName = Dir
    Loop

    With Application
         .DisplayAlerts = False
         wbAll.Sheets(1).Delete ' first blank sheet
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    wbAll.SaveAs FOLDER & "Combined.xlsx"
    MsgBox n - 1 & " sheets copied to " & wbAll.Name, vbInformation

End Sub
```